# sql find difference value between two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have two tables table1 and table2.
Table1 has data from the start of the year until **today**
and
Table2 has data from the start of the year until **yesterday**.
There are difference value in a specific field(field1) from table1 and table2.

Example.

```
table 1 field1(5)
table 2 field1(3)
```

The row in tables its not new,it can be inserted a days earlier.
I need to find the difference in the specific field that has **updated(changed)**not only inserted(new row).

```
Table1
------
John    | 3
George  | 2
Bill    | 1
```

```
Table2
------
John    | 3
George  | 1
Bill    | 0
```

the result i want is from table1

```
George   | 2
Bill     | 1
```

I hope it helps.

Thank you very much

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Do you know which rows should be matched between table1 and table2? Would you like to share?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: If you have a unique `Id` in each table, create a hash for each row and then compare the tables joining them with the ids and selecting rows where the hashes don't match. You can then compare the individual columns to find which fields are different.

Comment: Hello,thank you for your fast respond.I use pgsql.i updated the post

Comment: @siddharth i dont have unique id but your idea is so great.

Comment: Does the field which' values may differ is defined as `NOT NULL` in table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not interested in new rows, you can use simply this:

```
select t.* from table1 t join table2 t2 
      on t.name = t2.name where t.value <> t2.value;
```

If you want also the new rows in t1, then:

```
select t.* from table1 t left join table2 t2 
    on t.name = t2.name 
    where t.value <> t2.value or t2.name is null;
```